# Unable to auto-push newly generating scripts in the custom folder

Tags: protractor, allure

Instead of `custom-folder`, the json data is still populated under `allure-results`

```
onPrepare: function () {
    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
          allureReport : {
              resultsDir : 'custom-folder'
          }
      }));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try using absolute path and check whether you can able to generate the reports in custom path.

```
onPrepare: function () {
var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
var path = require('path');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
      allureReport : {
          resultsDir : path.resolve("./") + '/custom-folder'
      }
  })); 
};
```